# How can I execute the creation of user for psql using a bash?

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I am trying to do that :

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c 'psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD "qwerty";"'
```

I put that in a file and execute but it does not work ...

I suppose it is because of quote and double quotes ...

How can I do to create a user for psql using a bash file ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Strings in SQL require single quotes. You can use

```sh
sudo -H -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'qwerty'"
```